# Convert SQL Server Delete statement to use inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, sql-delete

My goal is to convert the below query to use inner join.

```
 DELETE ##TABLE1     
 FROM ##TABLE1 A,  ##TABLE2 B     
 WHERE A.VND_ACCT_NUM in (select distinct VND_ACCT_NUM from ##TABLE2)
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't seem right:

```
 DELETE ##TABLE1     
 FROM ##TABLE1 A
 INNER JOIN ##TABLE2 B     
 ON A.VND_ACCT_NUM in (select distinct VND_ACCT_NUM from ##TABLE2)
```

My task is to convert the first query to use the inner join syntax.

Comment: We like code blocks for a reason - they give us syntax highlighting and prevent important spacing details from being accidentally removed. Please leave them in your question.

Comment: Do be careful using global temp tables. They can often cause concurrency issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just match the tables up directly:

```
 DELETE FROM A     
 FROM ##TABLE1 A
 INNER JOIN ##TABLE2 B     
 ON A.VND_ACCT_NUM i= B.VND_ACCT_NUM
```

SQL Server doesn't mind if you attempt to delete the same row multiple times by such a join. Also, the `... IN(SELECT DISTINCT ...` was pointless anyway since `IN` returns true as soon as it has located one qualifying row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 DELETE A     
 FROM ##MX_DEALS A
 INNER JOIN ##MX_DAR_ISSUE_DEALS B     
 ON A.VND_ACCT_NUM in (select distinct VND_ACCT_NUM from ##MX_DAR_ISSUE_DEALS)
```